# Bad value " " for attribute "value" expected digit saw " ", getting this error

Tags: java, html, jsp

Id: <input type="number" name="Id" value="<%= property.getId()%>

Getting the error when I try this code for integer values... I tried parsing so that's not the problem

Comment: try with `value="<%=property.getId()%>` with no spaces between `%=` and `property.getId()`

Comment: It is still showing the same error

Comment: Make sure that datatype of getId() is Integer in pojo.